# display mysql-table - wrong order displayed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

php snippet:

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"dbtest");
$sql="SELECT * FROM w3school";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


echo "<ul id='myUL'>";
while($w3school = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<li id='".$w3school['id']."'>" . $w3school['LastName'] . "</li>";
}
echo "<ul>";
```

SCREEN OUTPUT looks like this:

```
id = 5;
id = 4;
id = 3;
id = 1;
id = 2;
```

I don't see why its not 1,2,3,4 ...

Any suggestions? (any spec info just let me know)

Comment: Order is not guaranteed in SQL without an `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: that is pointless degrading my question - the point was I couldn't find the other answer, because I didn't know about the order property. So I didn't even know what to search for in the first place.

Comment: you degraded your question by yourself not searching the web for `mysql order` before opening a question on SO. You are supposed to do some minimal research before posting a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the point is I only saw the problem and didn't see 'order' otherwise I wouldn't have had to ask, because I would already have known the solution...

Answer (score 0):

You need an `order by` for your query.

```
SELECT * FROM w3school order by id
```

Comment: wow, that was easy. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use order by where filed need to order as like you want to order by id -> 1,2,3,4...

```
SELECT * FROM w3school order by id asc;
```

or simple

```
 SELECT * FROM w3school order by id; // no need to add asc, default asc
```

And if you want 6,5,4,3,2,1 then use order by desc like

```
SELECT * FROM w3school order by id desc;
```

you can use multiple order by like this

```
SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY key_part1 DESC, key_part2 ASC;
```

more information

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html